# Eclipse too slow and unresponsive

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, acceleo, eclipse-sirius

[image]i use EMF framework, Sirius, Acceleo for a new eclipse plugin me and my team mate is working on. The problem is, everytime i want to try and run the plugin we already developed, eclipse took way too long to start, iam not talking about 30 second or 4 menutes long, it literally takes 3 hour more just to start, is there any way to fix thi or to fasten up the process without uninstaling all the plugin i need(Sirius, Acceleo, EMF), this issue happen after i download acceleo and Sirius to be used in developing my app

Comment: Are Eclipse, your workspace, and your runtime workspace all on a fast, local disk? Are you giving it enough physical memory? Have you tried using a current release? 2020-12 was 9 releases ago.

Comment: There is clearly something major wrong with your setup. Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there are any messages.

Comment: The project we are working required us to use the 2020 release so i cannot change it to latest version

Comment: i try to look at my .log file but i cannot understand anything, how can i send the log file here